# How to make Jackson continue parsing on JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a solution that allows Jackson to continue to parse JSON after recognizing a structural problem with the JSON that would cause a `JsonMappingException`, collect up all of the problems and return them all with one composite mapping exception?

In the example below, there are two properties in the JSON input that do not meet the `Person` class, but Jackson stops on encountering the first one.

It would be great to be able to collect the information about ALL structural problems for use in client side display.

```
class JacksonValidationHandlingSpec extends Specification {
    @Canonical
    static class Person {
        String firstName
        String lastName
    }

    @Test
    void "Unknown fields"() {
        setup:
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            UnrecognizedPropertyException upe
            try {
                mapper.readValue("""
                {"firstName":"john",
                 "lastName":"doe",
                 "middleName": "d",
                 "anotherUnknownField": "a"}
                """, Person.class)
            } catch(UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {
                upe = e
            }
        expect:
            upe != null
            upe.getPath().get(0).getFieldName() == "middleName"
    }
}
```